# Can a custom filter read property value and use it?

Tags: game-engine, properties, blur

the built in filters has some settings, like motion blur has amount. but it' cant be assign with logic bricks.

now a custom filter, can it read a value somehow (python code wont work? or would it... like own["blur_amount"] ? )

the shaders is C code it looks like, and doesn't need to have .py extension AFAIK.

anyways, this would be so awesome, also for built in filters. so we can enable/disable and maybe script with python the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have a game property in a GLSL shader.

[Here](http://solarlune-gameup.blogspot.com/2011/03/opengl-2d-screen-filters-in-bge-part-3.html) is a good read on making exactly what you want, a blur filter with a controlled blur amount from a game property (plus blend file).

From the script linked above, you can just use the property name *blur_amount* in the GLSL script.

Declare the var like this, then use *blur_amount* however you want to.

```
uniform float blur_amount;
```